# String List with Index and Sort option

Tags: c#

I need to add string values to a string List and every added string value will have its own integer index. When all values added I need to sort string List by index and read all strings from the list. I am not sure what List to use which could accept two parameters(string index and string itself) and will have Sort option. Any suggestion?

My list example

```
6 MyString1
1 MyString2
9 MySTring3
2 MyString4
```

Comment: What are the index values? (Will they be sparsely populated, for example?) Do you need any ordering *other* than by index?

Comment: @Jon, Index will be Integer value. I will update my post with example.

Comment: "Integer value" doesn't help us much. For example, for a list of three strings, will the indexes always be 0, 1 and 2 - or could they be -100, 10000 and 5000? Will they always be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you *may* just want [`SortedList<int, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) or [`SortedDictionary<int, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) but it will depend on your exact requirements, which aren't clear at the moment. Both of these classes are always sorted by key - you don't *explicitly* sort. What do you need to do with the list?

Comment: I think SortedList is that I need, I will test and let you know! Thank you!

Comment: @Tomas: Just bear in mind that `SortedList` is *really* a key/value mapping, it's just stored internally in an always-sorted list.